Unable to get access token from myanimelist.net
node.js code 

router.post('/accessToken', async (req, res) => {debugger const { client_id,client_secret , grant_type, code, redirect_uri, code_verifier } = req.body;

const basicAuth = Buffer.from(${client_id}:${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}).toString('base64');

try { const body = new URLSearchParams({ client_id: client_id, client_secret:client_secret, grant_type: grant_type, code: code, redirect_uri: redirect_uri, code_verifier: code_verifier }).toString();
// Log the request details (be careful not to log sensitive information in production)
console.log('Request details:');
console.log('URL:', 'https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token');
console.log('Headers:', {
  'Authorization': 'Basic [REDACTED]',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   
});
console.log('Body:', body);

const tokenResponse = await axios.post('https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/token', {
  client_id: client_id,
  client_secret:client_secret,
  grant_type: grant_type,
  code: code,
  redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
  code_verifier: code_verifier
}, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Host': 'myanimelist.net',
      'Authorization': `Basic ${basicAuth}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'MyAnimeListClient/1.0'
    }
});

const { access_token, refresh_token } = tokenResponse.data;

// Store the tokens securely (e.g., in a database)
// ...

res.json({ message: 'Authentication successful', access_token, refresh_token });
} catch (error) { console.error('Error obtaining access token:', error.response?.data || error.message); console.error('Full error object:', JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)); res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error obtaining access token', details: error.response?.data || error.message }); } });

React.js code 
 

fetch('http://localhost:3001/accessToken',
 { method: 'POST',
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }, 
 body: JSON.stringify({ 
 client_id: clientId, 
 client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET, 
 grant_type: 'authorization_code',  // The type for this request 
 code: authorizationCode,           // The code you received from the authorization       redirect_uri: redirectUri,         // Ensure this is URL-encoded if necessary 
  code_verifier: codeVerifier,       // The code_verifier used in the authorization request  }), }) 
 .then((response) => response.json()) 
 .then((data) => { console.log(data.accessToken);  }) 
 .catch((error) => { console.error('Error obtaining access token:', error); });

I have sent precisely perfect credentials from react to fetch access token from node js, however i'm unable to get them and im encountering this error frequently.
{"error": "invalid_client","message": "Client authentication failed"}

Authorization code is being fetched and I'm using the same auth code to fetch access and refresh token from myanimelist, its a stalemate.
users.js:118 Full error object: {"message": "Request failed with status code 401","name": "AxiosError","stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401\n    at settle "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST","status": 401}

